# Replacing thick tire with thin tire

Tags: tire, replacement, speed, racing

I ride a Hero Sprint, with tire size 26 inch. The wheels are thick and become slow, given my cycle's weight. Is it possible for me to switch to thinner tires? If yes, what are the plus and minus points i might receive?

Comment: It is width.  Based on rim width there will be a minimum tire width.  Google it.

Comment: The often repeated meme is that wider tires have rolling resistance. It is true if you have the exact same tire casing and use the same pressure, which you probably don't do. Anyway, rubber thickness, tread pattern and casing matter more than tire width.

Comment: Note that there is "wide" and "thick'.  A wide tire may be quite smooth and be "thin" if you somehow measure it from inside to outside.  But if a tire has a coarse tread usually it's fairly thick.  It's the tread and the thickness (and tire pressure) that affect rolling resistance most -- tire *width* is only a minor contributor.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to use a thinner tire will depend on your wheel's interior rim width. The inner rim width will constrain how thin of a tire you can have. Take a look at the conversion chart below to see if you can use a thinner tire. (note this chart is conservative, many cyclist have gone thinner with no problems).

[image]

Thinner tires have less roll resistance, so that will help with the slowness. The flip side is it'll feel bumpier (but this is only noticeable at higher psi: 80+).

If you're interested to learn more, take a look at some material from the great Sheldon Brown: [Tires](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tires.html) & [Tire Sizing](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Thin** tires tend to be **faster**, **lighter** and **bumpier** on hard surfaces, whereas **fat** tires tend to be **more grippy** and **shock-absorbent** on soft and hard surfaces.

Links to more details [here](https://itstillruns.com/wide-vs-narrow-tires-6586564.html) and [here](https://www.exploratorium.edu/cycling/wheel3.html).